# Move zsh + prezto configuration to dropbox

Tags: bash, permissions, zsh, chown, prezto

[Many people](http://geek.michaelgrace.org/2013/10/save-and-load-bash-profile-from-dropbox/) like to move their bash profiles to a Dropbox folder so that they can have multiple machines with their same profile (usually, for those who have a custom and specific profile that they love). I would like to do the same thing with my zsh profile and [Prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto) framework.

I created a Dropbox folder in `/Users/me/Dropbox/Computer Preferences/zsh/` (I will refer to this as *DBFolder*, hereon) which I would like to store my Prezto configuration in.

Here is the process that I've pursued:

1. I downloaded Prezto and moved all the files in the download to *DBFolder*.
2. I created a symlink for all z* files within `{DBFolder}/.zprezto/runcoms/` The resultant symlinks live in `~/`.
3. I added these lines to my zshenv file:

   `export ZDOTDIR="$HOME/Dropbox/Computer Preferences/zsh"
   if [[ "$SHLVL" -eq 1 && -s "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zprofile" ]]; then
     source "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zprofile"
     path = /Users/me/bin
   fi`

I am now able to launch my zsh profile with Prezto configurations. However, my problem is now that my initial login fails to load the path:

```
/Users/me/.zshenv:22: permission denied: /Users/me/bin
$ whoami
#=> me
```

My questions is - Why am I unable to access `/Users/me/bin` when I am clearly logged in (via the `$ whoami`) where it is within my home directory?

Comment: The problematic line is probably `path = /Users/me/bin`. As it is written it's a syntax error (but shouldn't give you "permission denied", so I'm not sure if you copied faithfully). Anyway, you clearly meant `PATH=/Users/me/bin:$PATH`, or better yet, `PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH`.

Comment: I'd love it if you'd make that an answer!
Also, do you have any opinions on my process for moving this to Dropbox? Have I forgotten something silly? Have I overlooked something?

Comment: Does that solve your problem? I'll make it an answer if that's the case. "Do you have any opinions on my process..." Sure, here's what I think: since you symlinked all your runcoms to `$HOME`, you don't need to set `$ZDOTDIR` at all; and I personally prefer symlinks to `$ZDOTDIR`. Also, you don't need to source `.zprofile` yourself; it is sourced automatically for login shells. What you've written here also sources it in non-login shells; if that's what you want, you are doing it the wrong way. Non-login stuff goes into `env` or `rc`, depending on interactivity.

Comment: Moreover, checking `$SHLVL` equal to 1 is superfluous. Repeating the same path in `$PATH` (or `$path`, which is the array counterpart) isn't really a problem, it just adds a little bit more work when searching. If you really care about deduplicating, just do `typeset -gU path` at the end, which deduplicates your `path` array.

Comment: Do you believe this is worth a new question? You have some really solid points here that are work a _discussion_ but I'm not sure if should be a question entirely.

Comment: Regarding the redundancy of having symlinks to `~/` as well as `$ZDOTDIR` – I have removed all my symlinks to my home directory, except for `~/.zshenv` which contains the command for `export ZDOTDIR=...`. I did this because I want to make it as easy as possible to setup a new machine with my prezto configuration. If I remove the `$ZDOTDIR` command in .zshenv and leave all my symlinks, I'll need to create these symlinks for every new machine. Whereas, by leaving the `$ZDOTDIR` command, but removing the symlinks (except .zshenv), all I have to do is symlink .zshenv to my home directory. Agreed?

Comment: "Do you believe this is worth a new question?" Sorry I don't get it, what question are you talking about? Do you have another problem? Regarding provisioning of new machines, why don't you simply write a setup script that symlinks the necessary stuff (a setup/provision script can be much more, check out my https://github.com/zmwangx/dotfiles/blob/master/setup or https://github.com/zmwangx/dotfiles/blob/master/provision, for instance)? Having symlinks in `$HOME` makes editing more convenient, but that's just a personal preference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92527/discussion-between-cole-bittel-and-4ae1e1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic line is

```
path = /Users/me/bin
```

There are three problems:

1. `$path` is an array in Zsh; `$PATH` is the POSIX-compatible scalar.
2. `=` surrounded by spaces is a syntax error; assignment in POSIX shells should not contain spaces.
3. `$PATH` should be extended rather than overwritten.

Correction:

```
PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

or

```
path=($HOME/bin $path)
```

The latter requires the `ksharrays` option to be off (off by default).

Comment: Converting comment to answer to get this out of the unanswered queue.